# Jest test error: ...subscribe is not a function

Tags: reactjs, angular, jestjs

I'm using Jest to test my Angular app (using Nx workspaces). I have a component that uses a service that I'm trying to mock. Here's the code:

```
myDummyService.permissions$.subscribe(permission => return // whatever);
```

In my test I mock the service like this:

```
myDummyServiceMock = {permissions$: jest.fn()}
```

But when the test runs and the constructor is invoked I get the following error:

```
`myDummyService.permissions$.subscribe is not a function`
```

I can't mock the subscribe function, so how can I get around this error? I tried this but I don't think it's right:

```
myDummyServiceMock = {permissions$: jest.fn(), subscribe: jest.fn()}
```

And if I do this then it works, but is it bad form?

```
myDummyServiceMock = {permissions$: of(true)}
```

Comment: Why `jest.fn` to start with? You don't _call_ `permissions$ `. So then of course subscribe isn't a function, because that's not a property functions have. Your second test double adds the subscribe property, but to _the wrong thing_ (the service itself, not the property you're accessing). In general: test doubles need to have the same interface as the thing they're replacing. So your third one is fine, because it does match the interface, with a property that's an observable.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - thank you very much for the explanation, it makes sense. i used jest.fn() at first because i know that's how you mock methods of a service....but here the permission$ behavior subject clearly isn't that. but that property of the service does need to return an observable so that's why the last solution works. thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all `permission$` is a property, not a function, secondly, it should be an observable. Therefore it should be defined properly, for example with help of `EMPTY` from `rxjs`.

```js
myDummyServiceMock = {permissions$: EMPTY};
```

Now it has `subscribe`, `pipe` and other methods.

If you want to manipulate its emits, you can use a `Subject` instance instead of `EMPTY`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm new to Jest and only knew how to mock functions, not properties. Now I know that if I want to mock it with some data then I just subscribe to it as I would a normal Observable. Thank you so much for the explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately, mocking observables without using another observables is complex. The easiest way is to use EMPTY to suppress any emits or Subject, to mock emits. Maybe npm has a package for jest, but out of the box, jest works with promises only.

Comment: Good to know. For the simplest of test cases for a component, I just needed to mock the service and its observable to prevent it from throwing an error when i ran the test suite. as i update the tests, surely i'll have to expand that functionality.

Comment: `{ permissions$: new Subject() }` will also work and give it a subscribe function